# How to run Python code and obtain its result in the minibuffer

Tags: python

I am using the following [answer for How do you run Python code using Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25687205/2402577).

I was wondering instead of opening python shell using `C-c C-z` and running `C-c C-c` to get results;

=> Can only the output results show up on the mini-buffer?

Opened Python shell buffer takes half of the window. I just want to see the output results in the minibuffer, or most compact buffer windows as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to use `call-process` or `shell-command-to-string`.  Here is an example:

```lisp
(defun python-fn (code)
  (let* ((temporary-file-directory ".")
         (tmpfile (make-temp-file "py-" nil ".py")))
    (with-temp-file tmpfile
      (insert code))
    (car (split-string (shell-command-to-string (format "python %s" tmpfile)) "\n$"))))

(python-fn "a = 150
b = 125
if b > a:
  print(\"b is greater than a\")
elif a == b:
  print(\"a and b are equal\")
else:
  print(\"a is greater than b\")")
```

Comment: How could I run it? `M-x` does not see `python-fn` ? `C-c C-c` did not make any change :-( I am getting: `‘shell-command-to-string’ is not a valid command name`, but I have something called `shell-command+` which seems like working but also generates `stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
` output too

Comment: A function can be made *interactive* (so that you can use `M-x`) by adding `(interactive)` to the first line of a `defun` that contains code.  If the `defun` contains an *optional* doc-string, then the `(interactive)` statement goes *below* the doc-string.  This example/answer is *not* meant to be used *interactively*.  You can paste the example/answer to the `*scratch*` buffer and place your cursor just *after* the *last* closing parenthesis of each code snippet and type `C-x C-e`, which is bound to `eval-last-sexp`.  I have never used `shell-command+` and do not know where it is defined.

Comment: Likewise, `shell-command-to-string` is *not* an `interactive` function.  I am hesitant to write up an example/answer that is made to be used interactively because the `python` language is rather finicky in terms of code indents, and I want to avoid opening a *Pandora's Box* that may create a lot of work.

Comment: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/shell-command+.html ; here I can do `python run.py` and it runs the code and prints its output. ; `emacs` couldn't find `shell-command-to-string` in `package-install` section. //

Comment: I opend a python file but I was not able to run `python-fn` or `C-x C-e` make it work :-( // `shell-command+` is equivalent to `shell-command`. Maybe if I can learn the current buffer name ; I can send it to `shell-command` as ./buffer-name.py to run it

Comment: My example/answer relates to using `shell-command-to-string`, *not* `shell-command` and *not* `shell-command+`.  If you are in a `python` file-visiting buffer and you want to run the most *recent* version that was *saved* to the hard drive, you could type `M-:` aka `M-x eval-expression` and paste `(car (split-string (shell-command-to-string (format "python %s" buffer-file-name)) "\n$"))` and then press the `RET` key.  If you arelady know the file name, you could input/paste `(car (split-string (shell-command-to-string (format "python %s" "/path/to/file.py")) "\n$"))`.

Comment: seems like `(defun run ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (format "python %s" buffer-file-name)))` works ; I kind of figure it out from your answers